# Angularjs replace existing emoji display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, emoji

Im displaying these emoji from my API, this is what it looks like in my browser :
[image]

but I want them to look something like these when displayed in my browser : 
[image]

I tried using [angular-emoji-filter](https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter) to do so but it didn't do the job, I guess Im misusing the module. How do I do that with `angularjs`?

This is me running from my mistake -> :running: :laughing:

**EDIT**
**HTML**
`<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="emoji">{{ message }}</p>`

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when using angular-emoji-filter? Are you adding the module correctly to your project? Do you have any code samples you can provide?

Comment: @WesCopeland yes all is fine, please see edit. That's my `HTML`

Comment: that's not how the `filter` is meant to be used at all.  perhaps you should review the documentation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module is a custom filter, you would use it the same way you use any angular filter.

Try the following instead:

```
<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="message | emoji"></p>
```